# How to use async/promise in render of Route in react router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am new to react-router v4. How would we do something like this in react router v4?

```
<Route path="/foo" render={props => {
  asyncMethod(props).then(() => <Foo />)
}} />
```

Comment: What are you doing in `asyncMethod()` ? Can't this be done in `Foo.componentWillMount()` ?

Comment: Usually, I will do authentication process in `asyncMethod`. If fails, will redirect to login again.

Comment: Check `PrivateRoute` from [react-router example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)